# Firebase Signout function not redirecting to login screen on expo react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am developing an ExpoReact Native mobile app and I am struggling to figure out how to redirect the user to the login screen after running the firebase.auth().signOut() method. I imagine it is something I am not understanding with nested navigators, but I would assume that once I run the signout method my AppNavigator.js useEffect function will catch the change in user state in the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged method and then rerender the screen to be the correct stack navigator. Please help me understand how to get this redirect working properly and why my current build is not working.

Below is my main App.js file, the AppNavigator.js file which holds the nested navigators, and the ProfileScreen.js file where I am running the sign out method on a button click.

App.js

```
import React from 'react'

import MainStackNavigator from './src/navigation/AppNavigator'

export default function App() {
  return <MainStackNavigator />
}
```

AppNavigator.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { firebase } from '../firebase/config';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { LoginScreen, HomeScreen, RegistrationScreen, ProfileScreen } from '../../screens'
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
if (!global.btoa) {  global.btoa = encode }
if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()

function MainTabNavigator() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        activeColor="#fb5b5a"
        inactiveColor="white"
        barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#465881' }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen 
            name='Home' 
            component={HomeScreen} 
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Home',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
                ),
              }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
            name='Profile' 
            component={ProfileScreen} 
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={26} />
                ),
              }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    )
  }

function MainStackNavigator() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
          console.log('Authenticated user')
          console.log(user)
        usersRef.doc(user.uid).get()
          .then((document) => {
            const userData = document.data()
            setLoading(false)
            setUser(userData)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false)
          });
      } else {
        console.log('signed out user')
        console.log(user)
        setLoading(false)
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      
        <View>
            <Text>Loading</Text>
        </View>
      
    )
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        { user ? (
            <>
                <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={MainTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MainStackNavigator;
```

ProfileScreen.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import { firebase } from '../../src/firebase/config'

export default function Profile() {

    const onSignoutPress = () => {
        firebase.auth().signOut()
        .then(console.log('signed out'))
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Profile Tab</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={() => onSignoutPress()}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Sign Out</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i noticed this problem too, so i placed the user instead than in a state in a context (so it can be shared between components) and i checked the login status on userLogged state instead than 'user'

```
const [userLogged, setUserLogged] = useState(false);
```

and in the useEffect part, set it as a result of

```
const authListener = Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
 setUserLogged(user ? true : false);
```

Then you can use it
{ userLogged == false ?

instead of

```
{ user ?
```

also let the useEffect return the authListener

Answer (score 0):

you should track if the user is logged in or not in some way for example using a state like this:

```
    const App = ({ navigation }) => {
    ...
     const [userLogged, setUserLogged] = useState(false); // it keep tracks of user login status
    ...
}
```

so you can use this state to check show the user the login or logged in page/stack with an if statement

the userLogged state can be constantly updated as result of a Firebase authListener for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const authListener = Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setUserLogged(user ? true : false);
     
    });
    return authListener;
  }, []);
```

this way when the app is started a Firebase authListener is set up and it is listening on auth state changes (Firebase.auth().signOut() for example), updating the userLogged state

when you render your stack navigation, you can check the status like when the user is not logged it shows a login screen (and a following signup screen), otherwise it shows the home screen (with a logout button):

```
<AppStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
            {userLogged == false ? (
              <>
                <AppStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />

                <AppStack.Screen
                  name="Signup"
                  options={{ title: loc.t('signup') }}
                >
                  {() => <SignUpScreen />}
                </AppStack.Screen>
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <AppStack.Screen
                  name="Home"
                  component={HomeScreen}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
              </>
            )}
          </AppStack.Navigator>
```

i have a small app (on github) along with a tutorial that would explain all this process in detail:
https://medium.com/react-native-playground/react-native-firebase-email-authenticaton-in-an-expo-project-2e413e9a4890

Comment: thanks for the response, but I thought I was already doing what you are suggesting.  In my AppNavigator.js file you can see near the bottom in my MainStackNavigator function that I am keeping track of the logged in user 'const [user, setUser] = useState(null)' and setting it in the useEffect method. Even when I console.log the information I can see that it is in fact capturing that user data correctly. I am confused why the correct navigation stack does not then appear.

Comment: can you try something like